# Rename excel file when exporting a datatable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, sweetalert

I am using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html). I added [Export to Excel button](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5). On click, a prompt will show up and ask you to enter filename.

```
filename: function () { 
var txt = prompt("Enter the filename :");
return txt; }
```

It works fine but I want to use [SweetAlert input](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/)  as visually it looks better.
The problem is the prompt shows up but the file is exported before the user types the filename.

```
swal("Enter the filename :", {
  content: "input",
})
.then((value) => {
  return value;
});
```

I am returning the input value directly after typing the filename. Any suggestions please what I am missing in my code ? Thank you very much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
"dom": 'Btri',
"searching" : false,
"paging" : false,
"info" : false,
buttons: [ {
extend: 'excelHtml5',
className: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm',
text: 'Export',
autoFilter: true,
attr:  { id: 'exportButton' },
sheetName: 'data',
title: '',
filename: function () { 
//var txt = prompt("Enter the filename :");
//return txt; 
swal("Enter the filename :", {
  content: "input",
})
.then((value) => {
  return value;
});
}
}]

} );

  
        
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround can be based on adding a mousedown event to the button.

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', '#exportButton', function(e) {
    swal("Enter the filename :", {
        content: "input",
    }).then(function (value) {
        if (value.trim().length > 0)
            $('#exportButton').data('filename', value).trigger('click');
    });
})
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "dom": 'Btri',
    "searching": false,
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    buttons: [{
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        className: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm',
        text: 'Export',
        autoFilter: true,
        attr: {id: 'exportButton'},
        sheetName: 'data',
        title: '',
        filename: function ( ) {
            return $('#exportButton').data('filename');
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>




<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```